# Selenium WebDriver difference between manual tests run and scripts execution

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to create a script to tests an application which performs searches. When I am launching a browser manually and perform a search manually everything works fine. But when I am doing the same using selenium script when selenium clicks the Search button, browser shows loading bar and it loads endless. I can't get to results page.

Does anyone meet such issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not be that helpful with my answer, but no: My selenium scripts were always running and the page was responding. Sometimes I had strange behavior which was fixed mainly by:

- Switching drivers - from FirefoxDriver to ChromeDriver and vice versa
- Upgrading browsers to the newest version available
- Upgrading Selenium to newest version
- Veryfying the test by running it in Selenium IDE first and then via WebDriver

Another guess:

- You can still run the FirefoxDriver with custom profile. Try running it through the same profile as you are using during the manual testing.

Comment: This issue is reproducible for IE6. And my gold is to run tests against this browser only. :-(

Comment: On completly unrelated topic: Do you know that worldwide share of IE6 dropped below 1 procent? :) But if you are still using IE6 inside your company, its bad... I cannot help more, because I dont have IE6 installed anywhere...